# What is the appropriate way to scale the cursor in Java?

Tags: java, cursor

I have a piece of code that scales a JPanel in the paintComponent() method as follows:

```
g2d.translate(this.getWidth()/2, this.getHeight()/2);
g2d.scale(scale, scale);
g2d.translate(-this.getWidth()/2, -this.getHeight()/2);
```

I expected this to scale the cursor of the JPanel as well, however it does not. I tried creating a custom cursor with a larger image, but it automatically re-sizes it to 32x32. Is there a system-independent way of resizing a cursor to match the scale of my JPanel?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you may 'suggest' differently sized cursor images, but the operating system always has the final say. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getBestCursorSize(int, int)

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought. I will maybe have to play with a mouse listener and paint a "cursor" wherever user has the mouse on the JPanel. Thanks.